# Toggle height of inline Div JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got stuck while animating the height of the `div`.There are multiple div with css `float:left`.When I `click` the particular div its height should increase.But since its height is increasing all the other div's position is also changing.I dont want them to change their position.What I want is that the div just below the `target` div should move down without affecting the other div's.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6md9wrxL/)

Here is the code.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 1
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 2
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 3
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 4
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 5
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 6
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 7
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 8
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 9
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 10
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses columns. You can resize the window and the columns are repopulated:

```js
var $boxes;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $boxes = $(".box");
 setupColumns();
  $(window).on("resize", setupColumns);
});

function setupColumns() {
 var $columnwrapper = $("#columns");
  var w = $("<div>").addClass("column").width();
  var cnt = Math.floor($columnwrapper.width() / w);
  var cols = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
   var $col = $("<div>").addClass("column");
    cols.push($col);
  }
  $columnwrapper.append(cols);
  var cnt = 0;
  $boxes.each(function () {
   $(this).detach().appendTo(cols[cnt]);
    cnt = (cnt + 1) % cols.length;
  });
}

$(".box").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.column {
  width: 114px;
  float: left
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="columns"></div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 1
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 2
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 3
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 4
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 5
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 6
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 7
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 8
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 9
</div>
<div class="box">
  HELLO WORLD 10
</div>
```

Comment: although this fiddle only works in mozilla but after a few changes it works fine in all the browser.

Comment: Right, I actually feared calculating the width like that might not work, but it did in Firefox, then I forgot to check.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to clear the float on every new row. I would suggest to change it from `float: left;` to `display: inline-block;`, and don't forget to add `vertical-align: top;`.

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7thmr9o/)**

Comment: This is similar to what I am looking for,but I want that the div in the column of the target divs should move down not the other divs

Comment: If that is the case, you'd have to have a max-height and keep it empty. That way when it stretches, the others won't move. Except if you want it to climb the others as it stretches.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal I see, can you put each group of blocks into a column? so they will be in multiple columns.

Comment: Actually these div are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

One way to toggle the elements' height without affecting the position of surrounding divs would be to absolutely position an item in the existing divs, then toggle that height instead.

```js
$("span").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 1
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 2
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 3
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 4
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 5
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 6
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 7
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 8
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 9
</span></div>
<div><span>
HELLO WORLD 10
</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "article" ).click(function() {
    if ( $(this).height() != 300)
          $( this ).animate({ height: 300 }, 1000 );
    else
          $( this ).animate({ height: 200 }, 1000 );
});
```

```css
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 45%; /* or fixed amount */
    margin-right: 5%; /* or fixed amount */
}

article {
  border:1px solid;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    background-color: #f6f6f8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
    <article>
        <h2>Phasellus Molestie Magna</h2>
        <p>Sed molestie augue sit amet leo consequat posuere. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Ut In Nulla Enim</h2>
        <p>Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Curabitur Vulputate</h2>
        <p>In condimentum facilisis porta. Sed nec diam eu diam mattis viverra. Nulla fringilla, orci ac euismod semper, magna diam porttitor mauris, quis sollicitudin sapien justo in libero. Vestibulum mollis mauris enim.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Suspendisse Dictum Feugiat Nisl</h2>
        <p>Curabitur vulputate, ligula lacinia scelerisque tempor, lacus lacus ornare ante, ac egestas est urna sit amet arcu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia.</p>
    </article>
</div>


<div class="column">
    <article>
        <h2>Donec Congue</h2>
        <p>Vivamus hendrerit arcu sed erat molestie vehicula. Sed auctor neque eu tellus rhoncus ut eleifend nibh porttitor. Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Proin Quis Tortor</h2>
        <p>Etiam at risus et justo dignissim congue. Donec congue lacinia dui, a porttitor lectus condimentum laoreet. Nunc eu ullamcorper orci. Quisque eget odio ac lectus vestibulum faucibus eget in metus. In pellentesque faucibus vestibulum. Nulla at nulla justo, eget luctus tortor. Nulla.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Praesent Id Metus Massa, Ut</h2>
        <p>Ut in nulla enim. Phasellus molestie magna non est bibendum non venenatis nisl tempor. Suspendisse dictum feugiat nisl ut dapibus. Mauris iaculis porttitor posuere. Praesent id metus massa.</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Just updated a fiddle here.. it may be what u want : `code` http://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/BqQF3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Also you should change your condition:

```
if ($(this).height() != 100)
```

into something like that:

```
if ($(this).hasClass( "div-100" ))
```

Just because in some cases `$(this).height() <> 100`. For example for Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (x64), and DPI Scaling Level for Displays in Windows 125%:

- zoom level 90% - `$(this).height() = 99.99999725097656`
- zoom level 100% - `$(this).height() = 100.00000457763672`
- zoom level 110% - `$(this).height() = 99.99999576416016`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.